# Why doesn't Samsung SM-J5008 (Lollipop) fire onReceive() after restarting?

Tags: android

I use Code A to do something after the system restart, and it's OK when I test the code in Android Emulator with API 22 and 23.

But I find that `onReceive` doesn't fire when I test it in real phone Samsung SM-J5008 with Android 5.1, why?

**Code A**

```
       <receiver android:name="bll.BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>



class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(mContext: Context, intent: Intent) {
       Log.e("My","Test")
    }


}
```

Comment: can you add `<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />` in your `intent-filter` and try again?

Comment: Thanks! I get the same problem after I add <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing to define permission of Boot complete receiver

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And If permission is already then trying with change bellow in your manifest.

```
<receiver
            android:name=".bll.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />, and meet the same problem

Comment: Thanks! I get the same problem after I add <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

Comment: One more thing this problem is only specific device or all?

Comment: I have only a real phone with Android 5.1 to test it, so I'm not sure if only my real phone meet the problem

Comment: Have you started the application at least once?

Comment: Here also one linke which help you more, https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the fully qualified name of your BroadCastReceiver in `<receiver android:name="YOUR_NAMESPACE.BootReceiver">` and see if it is working for you.

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me some sample code about passing the fully qualified name of my BroadCastReceiver in <receiver android:name="YOUR_NAMESPACE.BootReceiver">

Comment: At present, it's `<receiver android:name="bll.BootReceiver">`, and it can work in  Android Emulator with API 22 and 23